# Spring Boot 2 and logging configuration

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, logging

I'm trying to configure logging with my Spring Boot 2 application.

For example I'd like to see all `DEBUG` messages from `org.springframework.security` package.

I have added following properties to `application.properties` file(resource folder of Maven project):

```
#LOGGING
logging.level.root=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
```

but it have no effect.

I can see the same log messages in the console even without these properties.

How to properly configure logging with Spring Boot 2 ?

**UPDATED**

This is my current config:

```
#LOGGING
logging.level.root=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG
logging.level.org.neo4j.ogm=ERROR
logging.level.org.springframework.data=ERROR
logging.level.org.apache=ERROR
```

This is the [log file](http://www.thedownloadplanet.com/files/logs.txt)

but still no a single message from `org.springframework.security.*` package. This is my security config: [Spring Boot 2 and OAuth2/JWT configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45391264/spring-boot-2-and-oauth2-jwt-configuration)

**Maven poms:**

I have `parent pom` and two sub projects of this parent - `domain` and `api`. `api` also contains `domain` in dependencies.

**parent pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M3</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.exmple</groupId>
    <artifactId>exmple</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>exmple</name>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>${cdi-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>${jta.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-validator.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-io.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-compress.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jUnit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <modules>
        <module>domain</module>
        <module>api</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

**domain/pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <artifactId>exmple</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.exmple</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>domain</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <file.encoding>utf-8</file.encoding>

        <guava.version>19.0-rc1</guava.version>
        <owasp-java-html-sanitize.version>20160924.1</owasp-java-html-sanitize.version>
        <UserAgentUtils.version>1.20</UserAgentUtils.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- neo4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-kahadb-store</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-twitter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${guava.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.owasp-java-html-sanitizer</groupId>
            <artifactId>owasp-java-html-sanitizer</artifactId>
            <version>${owasp-java-html-sanitize.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.bitwalker</groupId>
            <artifactId>UserAgentUtils</artifactId>
            <version>${UserAgentUtils.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**api pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <parent>
        <artifactId>exmple</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.exmple</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>api</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.source.version>1.8</java.source.version>
        <java.target.version>1.8</java.target.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <com.exmple.domain.version>0.0.1</com.exmple.domain.version>

        <!-- 3rd party -->
        <spring.social.google.version>1.0.0.RELEASE</spring.social.google.version>
        <spring-social-github.version>1.0.0.M4</spring-social-github.version>

        <javaee-web-api.version>7.0</javaee-web-api.version>
        <rest-assured.version>2.9.0</rest-assured.version>
        <springfox-swagger2.version>2.6.0</springfox-swagger2.version>
        <sitemapgen4j.version>1.0.6</sitemapgen4j.version>
        <jaxb-api.version>2.2.12</jaxb-api.version>
        <quartz.version>2.3.0</quartz.version>
        <quartz-mongodb.version>2.0.0</quartz-mongodb.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- exmple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.exmple</groupId>
            <artifactId>domain</artifactId>
            <version>${com.exmple.domain.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Tomcat -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot Social Providers -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-facebook</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-linkedin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Social Providers -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-google</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.social.google.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-github</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-social-github.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- default j2ee dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javaee-web-api.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Swagger2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-swagger2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-swagger2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- sitemapgen4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.dfabulich</groupId>
            <artifactId>sitemapgen4j</artifactId>
            <version>${sitemapgen4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>${quartz.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.novemberain</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>${quartz-mongodb.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>${rest-assured.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.zip</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.zip</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.zip</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </testResource>
            <testResource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.zip</include>
                </includes>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.source.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.target.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    <useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>
                    <delimiters>
                        <delimiter>${*}</delimiter>
                    </delimiters>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Did  you check with  only `org.springframework` ? Maybe no class with the `security` subpackage is used.

Comment: I tried various packages - no effect :(

Comment: And is your application.properties well used at a time by Spring Boot ?

Comment: yes, no doubt  -  it is used a lot for many other things

Comment: So, maybe have you provided a logging configuration file that overwrites these  values ?

Comment: no, I have checked this. Also right now I have changed logging.level.root to DEBUG and now I can see a lot of messages. Is it possible to filter these messages with application.properties in order to be able to see messages only from a single specific package and it's sub-packages ?

Comment: @davidxxx I have updated my question with a current config.. still no luck

Comment: And adding only `logging.level.org=DEBUG` gives which result ?

Comment: more messages from org.neo4j.ogm.*, org.springframework.data.neo4j .. from 3rdparty packages but not from the spring* packages itself

Comment: I have added log file to my question so you can see the result

Comment: Attach you project structure please.

Comment: @PratikAmbani updated my question with a Maven poms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this for logging level and it works perfectly:

```
logging.level.com.foo.bar=DEBUG
```

where com.foo.bar is root package so change it with yours and try it out

Comment: I have reverted my changes to Spring Boot 1.5.7 and now this configuration working fine

Comment: Works well for me using spring-boot 2.2.4 & java 8.