# Spring Boot 2.0.0.M4 OAuth2 token endpoint throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to migrate from Spring Boot `1.5.7` to `2.0.0.M4`

Right now I'm unable to properly reconfigure my OAuth2 + JWT configuration on Spring Boot 2.0.0.M4

During startup, I noticed following errors for `/oauth/token` endpoint (`throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException`) in the log:

```
2017-10-04 09:52:46.841  INFO 11780 --- [           main] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/oauth/authorize],methods=[POST],params=[user_oauth_approval]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.View org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.AuthorizationEndpoint.approveOrDeny(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, ?>,org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus,java.security.Principal)
2017-10-04 09:52:46.842  INFO 11780 --- [           main] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/oauth/authorize]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.AuthorizationEndpoint.authorize(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>,org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus,java.security.Principal)
2017-10-04 09:52:46.843  INFO 11780 --- [           main] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/oauth/token],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.getAccessToken(java.security.Principal,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2017-10-04 09:52:46.844  INFO 11780 --- [           main] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/oauth/token],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.postAccessToken(java.security.Principal,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2017-10-04 09:52:46.845  INFO 11780 --- [           main] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/oauth/check_token]}" onto public java.util.Map<java.lang.String, ?> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.CheckTokenEndpoint.checkToken(java.lang.String)
2017-10-04 09:52:46.845  INFO 11780 --- [           main] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/oauth/confirm_access]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.WhitelabelApprovalEndpoint.getAccessConfirmation(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.lang.Exception
2017-10-04 09:52:46.846  INFO 11780 --- [           main] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/oauth/error]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.WhitelabelErrorEndpoint.handleError(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-10-04 09:52:46.848  INFO 11780 --- [           main] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/oauth/token_key],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenKeyEndpoint.getKey(java.security.Principal)
```

In order to reproduce this issue I hve created GitHub project - https://github.com/Artgit/spring-boot-2.0.0.M4-oauth2-token-issue/tree/master/api

I  order to produce this issue please try to execute `com.decisionwanted.domain.api.decision.DecisionControllerIT.testCreateDecision()` test

I apologize for the mess in the code and pom.xml. I have compiled this test project from the multimodule Maven application for test purpose.

Please help me fix my configs in order to be able work with Spring Boot `2.0.0.M4`

**UPDATED**

While debugging, I found that `server.contextPath: /api` from `application.properties` is not taking into account. Right now I need to use `/oauth/token` (instead of `/api/oauth/token` like I use with Spring Boot 1.5.7) in order to obtain the token. What can be a reason of this and how to fix it ?

Comment: Unfortunately your app's too large to understand in a reasonable amount of time so I can't precisely diagnose the problem. I can, however, run it with debug logging enabled for org.springframework.security and observe that requests to `/api/oauth/token` are being rejected due to an invalid CSRF token. Perhaps that helps to point you in the right direction?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson, thanks for your answer. While debugging, I found that `server.contextPath: /api` from `application.properties` is not taking into account. Right now I need to use `/oauth/token` (instead of `/api/oauth/token` like I use with Spring Boot 1.5.7) in order to obtain the token. What can be a reason of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason of the issue - according to the following documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/ with Spring Boot 2* the following property should be used in order to define context path of the application:

```
server.servlet.context-path= /api
```

Please note that Spring Boot 1.5.* property

```
server.contextPath: /api
```

is not more taken into account